# TypeScript - jasmine - Chutzpah - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, chutzpah

Hi we are using angulatJs with typescript.
For unit testing we are using Jasmine.
And to run jasmine we are using **Chutzpah**.

When i am trying to build project it giving me an error that

**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular**

Where i have added reference to the .spect.ts correctly.

```
 ///<reference path="../external/angularJS/1.0.8/angular.d.ts" />
 ///<reference path="../external/angularJS/1.0.8/angular-ui.d.ts" />
 ///<reference path="../external/angularJS/1.0.8/angular-mocks.d.ts" />
 ///<reference path="../_references.d.ts" />
```

But still i am getting the **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular**

Any suggestion ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those references are to the .d.ts file but Chutzpah needs to know where the actual implementation .js files are. You can do this using

```
/// <chutzpah_reference path="path/to/angular.js" >
/// <chutzpah_reference path="path/to/angular-ui.js" >
/// <chutzpah_reference path="path/to/angular-mock.js" >
```